# How to delay loading the scene to play the sound

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, time

How to delay loading the scene to play the sound?
I'm trying to delay loading a scene so I can play the sound, but the sound stops in the middle or doesn't exist at all and the scene changes immediately
Here is my script:

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MeinMenu : MonoBehaviour
{

    static AudioSource audioScr;
    public void NewGame()
    {

        SoundManagerScript.PlaySound("clik");
        DontDestroyOnLoad(audioScr.gameObject);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("level 1");
        
    }
    public void LoadGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SavedScene"));
    }
    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Happens when the scene loads faster than the sound can finish playing.
When a scene loads by default, it destroys all objects on the previous scene, which includes your audio source.

One way is to mark your audio-source with [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

```cs
// Somewhere after your audio source have loaded...
DontDestroyOnLoad(yourAudioSource.gameObject);
```

Note that this means you are likely to end up with a singular instance of Audio Source, as this audio source (or the game-object attached to it, to be exact) will only be destroyed manually via script.

---

The other is to just do a coroutine that does nothing until the audio source have finished playing:

```cs
    IEnumerator LoadSceneWithSoundCoroutine()
    {
        yourAudioSource.Play();

        // Denies loading while audio source is playing.
        while (yourAudioSource.isPlaying)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        SceneManager.LoadScene("Your scene")
    }

    // ...

    StartCoroutine(LoadSceneWithSoundCoroutine());
```

Comment: How to combine above code with DontDestroyOnLoad, because I tried but I keep getting error

Comment: @Viw0a i edited my answer to give more information

Comment: such an error pops up: error CS1061: 'AudioClip' does not contain a definition for 'gameObject' and no accessible extension method 'gameObject' accepting a first argument of type 'AudioClip' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Viw0a Audio**Source**, not AudioClip. AudioClip is not a component, therefore it isn't attached to a gameObject, hence not having a gameObject property.

Comment: sound works but now the game does not advance to the next scene and I get this error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. i edited the first script to preview

Comment: @Viw0a What object is the error pointing to? It is a null reference error where you didn't set some variables on inspector properly, or some variables weren't assigned.

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object MeinMenu.NewGame () (at Assets/Scrips/MeinMenu.cs:14 I think it's about DontDestroyOnLoad(audioScr.gameObject);